# Table Layout with textview after 3 rows

Tags: android, android-tablelayout

I am designing a layout that has 24 rows. Each row has 2 columns. And after every 3 or 4 rows there is a text view. Each row and text view has a click listener. On click of any row, I have to dynamically add text view to that particular row.

To do so, I have created a table layout that has total of 29 rows. 24 rows with 2 columns and instead of text view there is rows with 1 column. For each row there is separate listener and separate code for adding views to them. As a result, I my writing same lines of code for 24 times.This has made my application slow.

Is there any other way I can design my layout or optimize my code? Can I use list view instead of table layout?

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A better example in my view is [this tutorial here](http://www.survivingwithandroid.com/2014/08/android-listview-with-multiple-row.html); as it shows how you can create different layout for different row items. (Your some rows are different from others, where you have only one textView as compared to two columns).

So, now create two row layouts, one with only one textview inside, and other with a LinearLayout with two `TextView`.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"   
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal"> 

<TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:id="@+id/name"/> 

<TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:id="@+id/surname" 
android:layout_toRightOf="@id/name"
android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"/>
```

and on your `getView()` can check which number of row it is and assign appropriate layout for this, check the tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

You can inflate your own custom layout into the list view for each row using custom BaseAdapter. One OnItemClickListener will be sufficient to handle events of all the rows using position. see links below :

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html

http://androidexample.com/How_To_Create_A_Custom_Listview_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=67&aaid=92